# ios CLLocationManager won't get location second time

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location

I have a `getLocation` method that initializes my `CLLocationManager` and calls `startUpdatingLocation`. After I get the user's location, I call `stopUpdatingLocation`.

Later, when the user presses refresh, I call a method `reloadData` which calls `getLocation` so I can get the user's latest location. However, this never calls the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` 
method.. so I never get the user's latest location. What could be the issue?

```
-(void) getLocation {
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager 
 didUpdateToLocation: (CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (oldLocation!= nil) { // make sure to wait until second latlong value
        [self setLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        [self setLongitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
        self.locationManager = nil;
        [self makeUseOfLocationWithLat:[self getLatitude] andLon:[self getLongitude]];
    }
}

-(void) reloadData {
    [self getLocation];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the delegate method is not being called? It might be presenting cached data when it call again so it would have the save newLocation and you wouldn't notice any change.

Comment: i put an NSLog in the delegate method to see if it was getting called..and it wasn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary to allocate a new CLLocationManager? Try just allocate it once (in your init for example) and just call startUpdatingLocation and stopUpdatingLocation on demand.
For me, this solution works great.

Comment: I tried that too, but I noticed that I had another issue where if i didn't set the delegate to nil after stopUpdatingLocation..then sometimes I'd go into an infinite loop where the delegate method keeps getting called over and over. In any case, I don't think allocating a new CLLocationManager could cause the problem...or could it?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the beginning of getLocation so that you can really see what is happening and whether or not your have a valid location manager.

Answer (score 1):

Do you move during testing this? Because I think the callback will only be triggered, when:

- you call `startUpdatingLocation`
- your location changes
- the location manager gets better results (more detailed)

So I think for your use-case: as you don't move, the callback `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` will only be called once after you hit refresh and as there is no old location, you will not go into the `if` case.

Another thing: you should definitely have only one CLLocationManager in your class. I only use one per project/application (wrapped in a singleton). This is the preferred way to do! Also I think this will retain the oldLocation value so that your problem may be resolved by changing this.

Best,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ,this will help u to update for every time when open the page.Cause if u put startUpdatingLocation in viewdidload ,it will get load only for the first time

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```